# .htaccess to allow for file download if condition set

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the current rule to allow for a file's viewing

`RewriteRule ^ios/headers/([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/(.*).h$ /ios/headers/view.php?ios=$1&file=$2.h [L]`

I have a list of header files and I want to put them through a viewer unless I set the ?raw=yes tag, then I want the user to be able to download it (actually go to the file).

How would I achieve this?

Is there a better way to do this? Is .htaccess even this powerful?

Comment: So what's the problem with the rule?

Comment: The rule works great for viewing but I need another rule(?) for allowing the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the "raw=yes" using a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !raw=yes
RewriteRule ^ios/headers/([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/(.*).h$ /ios/headers/view.php?ios=$1&file=$2.h [L]
```

Then the rule won't get applied and the request won't get rewritten to `view.php`. Though, this is assuming that if you go directly to: `/ios/headers/123.234/foo.h`, you actually download `foo.h`. Otherwise, you'll need to add code in `view.php` for the `raw=yes` parameter and force the download through there.

Comment: This triggers the download for any condition (even just a ? after the .h). Fortunately that is fine with me! Thanks!